# How to solve 500 Internal Server Error in Swagger UI,service is not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Service is compiling
but shows error
500 in swagger ui and
not giving output help!
Below are controller, service,implementation codes ,please help me get through this.
Rest all services are working fine

> controller

```
@ApiOperation(value="Returns all bookings")                                             //Operation to view all bookings
    @ApiResponses(value= {
            @ApiResponse(code=201, message="All Bookings found"),
            @ApiResponse(code=404, message="No such booking found")
    })
    @GetMapping(value = "/booking/all", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
    public List<Booking> getAllBooking() throws BookingNotFoundException {
        logger.info("View all booking service started..");
        return bookingService.getAllBookings();
    }
```

> Service Implementation

```
@Override
public List<Booking> getAllBookings() {
    return  BookingUtil.convertBookingEntityListIntoBookingList(bookingRepo.findAll());
}
```

> Service

```
         public List<Booking> getAllBookings();
```

> util

```
public  static BookingEntity convertBookingIntoBookingEntity(Booking booking) 
{
    return new BookingEntity(booking.getJourneyDate(),booking.getBookingDate(),booking.getCancelDate(),
            booking.getFare(),booking.getBookingStatus(),booking.getVehicleType(),RouteUtil.convertRouteIntoRouteEntity(booking.getRoute()),
            UserUtil.convertUserIntoUserEntity(booking.getUser()));
}

public  static Booking convertBookingEntityIntoBooking(BookingEntity bookingEntity)
{
    return new Booking(bookingEntity.getBookingId(),bookingEntity.getJourneyDate(),bookingEntity.getBookingDate()
            ,bookingEntity.getCancelDate(),bookingEntity.getFare(),bookingEntity.getBookingStatus(),
            bookingEntity.getVehicleType(),RouteUtil.convertRouteEntityIntoRoute(bookingEntity.getRoute()),
            UserUtil.convertUserEntityIntoUser(bookingEntity.getUser()));
}

public static List<Booking> convertRouteEntityListIntoBookingList(List<BookingEntity> bookingEntityList) {
    List<Booking> booking = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    for(BookingEntity bookingEntity: bookingEntityList) {
        booking.add(convertBookingEntityIntoBooking(bookingEntity));
    }
    return booking;
}



public  static List<Booking> convertBookingEntityListIntoBookingList(List<BookingEntity> bookingEntityList)
{
    List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    for(BookingEntity bookingEntity: bookingEntityList) {
        bookings.add(convertBookingEntityIntoBooking(bookingEntity));
    }
    return bookings;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace on the service, the error should be logged there

Comment: it's done, forgot to create a default constructor in entity that threw the error,anyways, thankyou! :)